# Django templates do not respect DateTimes in different timezone

Tags: python, html, django, datetime

In my Django app, I am storing all the DateTime objects as aware objects in UTC. But my users may live in different parts of the world. So, I have set up a form for them to choose their respective time zone. In the backend, I have written Python code to first convert the corresponding DateTime objects to the local time zone using Django's `astimezone()` function. There is an attribute under the user's profile model that stores the timezone. So, all my code will actually do operations based on the user's local time while in the actual database they are stored as UTC. Now, I seem to have come across a problem and I can't see the reason why this should occur. In the app, I have made a dedicated page to show the users a comparison of the server time and their local time. This is my code

view function that renders that page

```
def check_time(request):
    " A view function that let's user view their local time and server time (usually UTC) at a glance"
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)

    server_time = timezone.now()
    user_localtime = server_time.astimezone(user.profile.timezone)

    context = {
        "server_time": server_time,
        "user_localtime": user_localtime
    }

    return render(request, "ToDo/check_time.html", context=context)
```

check_time.html

```
{% extends "ToDo/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<div class="content-section dark-mode-assist-section">
    <h1>Check if your local time is accurate</h1>
    <br><br>
    <h2>Server time: {{ server_time }}</h2>
    <h2>Your time: {{ user_localtime }}</h2>
</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

This is what happens:
[image]

Both of the times are the same. Although I had converted the time before passing it to the template. Why does this error occur?

Additional info:

- My `USE_TZ` is on
- My `TIME_ZONE` is "UTC"
- There is no `current time zone` setup in my app

Comment: In the example that you are trying, what's the parameter value are you passing into the `astimezone()` function? Are you also sure that user doesnt reside in a `UTC +- 0` region?

Comment: The `astimezone()` function won't accept strings like "US/Pacific". So, the parameter that goes into `astimezone()` is a tzinfo object that represents the current user's local ttime zone

Comment: Can you also clarify on my second point.

Comment: As for the second point, all the users' default timezone is UTC. And there is no option of any UTC +- 0. I think this is what you were asking. So, every user, if not set otherwise, has timezone UTC.

Comment: Rest assured, the `user_localtime` that is being passed to the template is the local time in the local timezone that the user has selected. I had printed this variable and I saw that it printed the user's time to the console. But Django template weirdly neglects the timezone and displays in UTC. It'd be greatly appreciated if you could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your last comment that the `astimezone()` is working correctly in your `views.py`  it seems like the error is happening in the templates. Most likely that it converts all time to `UTC` time as may be specified in your `settings.py` with `TIME_ZONE`.

You can enable or disable the conversion of datetime objects using templates tags:

```
{% load tz %}

{% localtime on %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocaltime %}

{% localtime off %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocaltime %}
```

You can also set `TIME_ZONE` and `USE_TZ` in `settings.py` to get around this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I appreciate it a lot. Turns out using `localtime off` worked. I think this template tag ignores the conversion to UTC. I just had one other query though. Since using `localtime off` does not convert the time to UTC, is `localtime on` and not using anything at all the same thing? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I would think that's the case. You can test it confirm it if you wish.

Comment: Cheers! Have a nice day!!